# WebSphere System Error log

Tags: websphere

We have Web Service application using SOAP API running on webpshere server which in turn has 2 server instances. One server instance log is good and while the other is writing  FATAL ERROR:  'java.lang.NullPointerException' :null in SystemErr log file even though application works fine. I am not sure what causing this and its not writing any stack trace in SystemOut log. Appreciate if anybody help on this.

Comment: Please, provide more info. Which version of WebSphere Application Server are you using? Which operating system? Did you check FFDC logs? You can find them in "<was_home>\profiles\<profile_name>\logs\ffdc\".

Answer (score 0):

I'd scan the application code for "FATAL ERROR:".  That might provide a clue.